# how can I add the ticking clock to my div in an existing code?

Tags: javascript, jquery

It's actually a follow up to this question [I want to display elements from json based on their time and duration and interval is interupted by settimeout](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/33002880/i-want-to-display-elements-from-json-based-on-their-time-and-duration-and-interv) - I accepted the answer there made by @Daniel Flint - his code is quite clear and can be found here http://jsfiddle.net/nauzilus/rqctam5r/

However, there's one more thing that I wanted to add - a simple div `<div id="time"></div>` that would contain a new date time object initialized during opening the page and then it being incremented every second just to show the current time constantly. I thought about writing there a javascript:

```
var actualTime = new Date(substractedDate); // taken from the server

function updateTimeBasedOnServer(timestamp) { 
    var calculatedTime = moment(timestamp);
    var dateString = calculatedTime.format('h:mm:ss A');
    $('#time').html(dateString + ", ");
    };

var timestamp = actualTime.getTime();

updateTimeBasedOnServer(timestamp);
    setInterval(function () {
        timestamp += 1000; // Increment the timestamp at every call.
        updateTimeBasedOnServer(timestamp);
        }, 1000);
```

(I provide the time of the server as a timestamp there).

I just noticed that there is a slight mismatch between displaying the time in my div and between the text appearing on the screen, possibly because I increment both of the values in two different places.

So my question is - how can I "merge" @Daniel Flint's code with mine and increment both values only in one place?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

One thing that jumps out here:

```
timestamp += 1000;
```

`setTimeout`/`setInterval` aren't guaranteed to run at precisely the delay you've entered. Run this in your browsers console:

```
var last = Date.now(),
    time = function() {
      var now = Date.now();
      console.log(now - last);
      last = now;
    },
    id = setInterval(time, 1000);
```

On my Mac at home (Chrome/FireFox) it was anywhere from 990 to 1015. Windows machine at work is a bit better (995-1002), but IE was getting up to 1020. It's not a huge difference, but it's not nothing.

So code needs to be able to handle not running exactly every 1000ms. That's why I was running the timer at 500ms intervals, and checking if the start time was less-than-equal to the current time.

I've rejigged the demo to show the time and message in sync:

```js
(function() {
  var messages = [];
  var time = document.getElementById("current-time");
  var display = document.getElementById("message");

  function check() {
    showMessage(currentMessage());
    showTime();
  }

  function currentMessage() {
    var message = null;
    if (messages.length) {
      var now = toTheSecond(new Date());
      var start = toTheSecond(new Date(messages[0].start_time));
      var end = toTheSecond(new Date(start.getTime() + ( messages[0].text_duration * 1000 )));

      if (start <= now) {
        if (end <= now) {
          // done with the current message...
          messages = messages.slice(1);
          // ...but check if there's another one ready to go right now
          message = currentMessage();
        }
        else {
          message = messages[0];
        }
      }
    }
    return message;
  }

  function toTheSecond(date) {
    date.setMilliseconds(0);
    return date;
  }

  function showMessage(message) {
    if (message) {
      display.textContent = message.text_content;
    }
    else {
      display.textContent = "no messages";
    }
  }

  function showTime() {
    time.textContent = new Date().toLocaleString()
  }

  function getMessages() {
    setTimeout(function() {
      var now = new Date();
      messages.push(
        {"text_content":"aaaaa","text_duration":5,"start_time": new Date(now.getTime() + 3000).toISOString()},
        {"text_content":"aawwaaaaa","text_duration":5,"start_time": new Date(now.getTime() + 10000).toISOString()},
        {"text_content":"bbaawwaaaaa","text_duration":5,"start_time": new Date(now.getTime() + 15000).toISOString()}
      );
    }, 1000);
  }

  setInterval(check, 500);
  getMessages();
})();
```

```html
<span id="current-time"></span> <span id="message">Hello there!</span>
```

(Putting the code here as well because I recall SO want code in the answers so it's controlled, but there's a demo here: http://jsfiddle.net/nauzilus/ymp0615g/).

This probably isn't as efficient as it could be; the message text is being set every iteration which might cause repaints/reflow. But then again setting the time stamp is going to do that anyway, so meh :)

Comment: Thank you, I really appreciate your effort in providing the answers, they are explained well enough and of course it's exactly what I'm looking for :) The very last question here is that currently we have there `now = toTheSecond(new Date());`, but I wanted to use the server time instead of user browser's time. In the previous code I used `new Date(substractedDate); // taken from the server` and then I had to increase this value every second <-- is it possible to do that with your proposed code?

Comment: Jeez I hate time :) So the `start_time` is server time (well, I guess it's important not to assume that time is the same timezone as the user anyway, which of course I have!).

I think you'd want to ensure you're returning the timezone in the `start_time`, and then I think it should all take care of itself in terms of showing messages at the correct time (if the timestamp is included JavaScript can parse the date appropriately for the local time, so it'll work).